# stringstream >> operator

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have this code:

```
    std::string s = "\n\n\n\n+\n\n\n+";
    std::stringstream serializedDataStream(s);

    std::string plusCharacter, plusCharacter2;
    serializedDataStream >> plusCharacter ;
    cout << "plusCharacter "<<plusCharacter << "\n";
    serializedDataStream >> plusCharacter2 ;
    cout << "plusCharacter "<<plusCharacter2;

    //OUTPUT:
    //    plusCharacter +
    //    plusCharacter +
```

which means that the `stringsteam` `>>` operator skipped new lines. I looked into the `std::stringstream` documentation but I couldn't find an explanation for why this is happening. Is this a compiler specific behavior, or can I rely on this?

Comment: Reading with `operator>>` ignores any preceding whitespace as standard. I'll dig up some documentation.

Comment: Yes, `operator>>` skips newlines until it finds something to read. Use `std::getline` if you want to read to a newline.

Comment: @chris, do you know where I can find this info? about skipping newlines? Also where I can find the actual behavior of >> of a stringstream, since it seams that >> will skip newlines until a char is found and then if you keep repeating the action (i.e. >>) it will keep going until a newline or space and somehow tokenize the stream. I can't find that anywhere

Comment: @Kam, It's in the standard somewhere. I've personally always gone off of it's just the way it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This occurs because `operator>>` behaves as a *formatted input function*. Part of the process of a formatted input function is:

> Each formatted input function begins execution by constructing an object of class sentry with the `noskipws` (second) argument false.

When `noskipws` is set to false (and the `skipws` flag on the stream being true, which is default), the `sentry` object "extracts and discards each character as long as the next available input character `c` is a whitespace character."

If you want to read each line at a time, use `std::getline`. This function behaves as an *unformatted input function* which has `noskipws` set to true and reads a line of text (as defined by the line terminator (parameter 3 of std::getline() (which defaults to '\n'))).

Answer (score 2):

[Read up here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)

> Behaves as an FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking
>   the sentry object, **which may skip leading whitespace**, extracts
>   successive characters and stores them at successive locations of a
>   character array whose first element is pointed to by s.

So as per the standard, it will toddle along whatever is in the stream until it actually finds something interesting, read that back to you, then stop. Then do the same again next time.

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) on the other hand will read *everything* up to the next newline character (this will be pulled off the stream but not given back to you) and gives it all back to you in a `std::string`. It is then up to you to get what you want (e.g. a number) from that `string`.

**Edit:** I'm struggling to find exactly *which* characters are considered to be whitespace by the default locale. I *think* it will be the same as defined for [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) (inherited from c), which are `space (0x20), form feed (0x0c), line feed (0x0a), carriage return (0x0d), horizontal tab (0x09) and vertical tab (0x0b).` But I haven't been able to convince myself 100% it is the same in this case. I'm not good with locales.

Comment: Thank you, but also as I mentioned in my comment above, how do I know what are the delimeters that stringstream uses ? i.e everytime I do >> on a stringstream it goes until where? a ws? or \n? or what is it?

Comment: @Kam It's only a click away from the link BoBTFish posted: "the next available character on the input stream is not a whitespace character, as tested by the std::ctype facet of the locale currently imbued in this input stream."